# Liquibase: changeLogPropertyDefined doesn't work

Tags: liquibase, preconditions

I'm trying to execute one of two insert depending on value of Java system property 'type'. But when I run updateSQL, it generates both insert entries despite of value and even presence of variable 'type'. This are my change sets:

```
 <!--changes for CS only-->
    <changeSet id="57" author="mborodin">
        <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
            <changeLogPropertyDefined property="type" value="cs"/>
        </preConditions>
        <sql>INSERT INTO cs.config(key, value) values('autochecks.findProfilesInDb', 'true'),
                ('web.type', 'cs'), ('globalFailureDetectorEnabled', 'true');
         </sql>
    </changeSet>

    <!--changes for LCS only-->
    <changeSet id="58" author="mborodin">
        <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
            <and>
                <changeLogPropertyDefined property="type" value="lcs"/>
                <not>
                    <changeSetExecuted
                            id="57"
                            author="mborodin"
                            changeLogFile="${changeLogFile}"
                            />
                </not>
            </and>
        </preConditions>
        <sql>INSERT INTO cs.config(key, value) values('autochecks.findProfilesInDb', 'false'),
            ('web.type', 'local-cs'), ('globalFailureDetectorEnabled', 'false');
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
```

What's wrong? Is there a better way to work it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first nvoxland's answer at [liquibase forum](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/unexpected-behaviour-of-preconditions-with-updatesql):

> … we added the onSqlOutput tag.  IGNORE just assumes that the
>   precondition cannot be applied, but you should continue to "run" the
>   changeLog.  TEST means to actually run the precondition.  FAIL mean to
>   stop the execution of the changelog, alerting you that you cannot run
>   in updateSql mode because a correct execution of the precondtion is
>   required to continue.

The problem has been solved by adding onSqlOutput="TEST" tag.